# Pandas pairwise arithmetic similar to rolling().corr()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation, pairwise

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
fsym                            EOS       BTC       BNB
time                                                   
2018-11-30 00:00:00+00:00 -0.051903 -0.069088 -0.058162
2018-12-01 00:00:00+00:00  0.026936  0.044739  0.040303
2018-12-02 00:00:00+00:00 -0.034843 -0.012935 -0.005900
2018-12-03 00:00:00+00:00 -0.108108 -0.070375 -0.028180
2018-12-04 00:00:00+00:00 -0.048583  0.019509  0.131986
```

I can calculate a column pairwise correlation simply with:

```
pt = pt.rolling(3).corr()
```

which yields:

```
sym                                 EOS       BTC       BNB
time                      fsym                              
2018-11-30 00:00:00+00:00 EOS        NaN       NaN       NaN
                          BTC        NaN       NaN       NaN
                          BNB        NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-12-01 00:00:00+00:00 EOS        NaN       NaN       NaN
                          BTC        NaN       NaN       NaN
                          BNB        NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-12-02 00:00:00+00:00 EOS   1.000000  0.952709  0.938688
                          BTC   0.952709  1.000000  0.999066
                          BNB   0.938688  0.999066  1.000000
2018-12-03 00:00:00+00:00 EOS   1.000000  0.998738  0.969385
                          BTC   0.998738  1.000000  0.980492
                          BNB   0.969385  0.980492  1.000000
...
```

How can I similarly calculate the pairwise differences for the dataframe? It would be the equivalent of using a rolling window of 1 I guess.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, the above example isn't actually a columnwise correlation which I hadn't noticed.

Comment: I don't think `pt = pt.rolling(3).corr()` are pairwise column correlation. They are pairwise last-3-day column correlation. Is that what you are trying to achieve with `difference`?

Comment: Yes... I see what you mean now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 9 columns:

```
# test data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(-1,3), columns=list('abc'))

s = df.values
new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, df.columns])

pd.DataFrame((s[:,None,:] - s[:, :,  None]).reshape(len(df), -1),
             index=df.index,
             columns=new_cols)
```

Output:

```
   a        b        c      
   a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
0  0  1  2 -1  0  1 -2 -1  0
1  0  1  2 -1  0  1 -2 -1  0
2  0  1  2 -1  0  1 -2 -1  0
3  0  1  2 -1  0  1 -2 -1  0
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to improve my use of numpy broadcasting and pandas together.

Answer (score 0):

The following function gets close to an adequate solution:

```
def columnwise_difference(df):          
    a = df.values
    r,c = pd.np.triu_indices(a.shape[1], 1)
    cols = df.columns
    nm = [cols[i]+"-"+cols[j] for i,j in zip(r,c)]
    return pd.DataFrame(a[:,r] - a[:,c], columns=nm, index=df.index)
```

which gives:

```
                            EOS-BTC   EOS-BNB   BTC-BNB
time                                                   
2018-11-30 00:00:00+00:00  0.017185  0.006259 -0.010926
2018-12-01 00:00:00+00:00 -0.017803 -0.013367  0.004436
2018-12-02 00:00:00+00:00 -0.021908 -0.028943 -0.007035
2018-12-03 00:00:00+00:00 -0.037733 -0.079928 -0.042195
```

...except I don't just want `np.triu_indices` but all 9 combinations including EOS-EOS etc. (there must be a simple change I can make to do that)